# Why are UIKit delegates "assign"ed instead of "weak"?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, uikit

As the title states, why are `UIKit` delegates `(assign)` instead of `(weak)`?

See `UIPopovercontroller.h` for example:

`@property (nonatomic, assign) id <UIPopoverControllerDelegate> delegate;`

As far as I can tell this provides no benefits over a weakly retained property but a lot of problems where the delegate needs to manage it's own lifetime as a delegate. It this a backwards compatibility issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because most of those properties existed before the iOS SDK supported weak properties. The `weak` attribute is only supported on iOS 5.0 and later.

I would have to guess that once iOS 4.x and earlier is history, they will all be updated to `weak`.

Comment: `weak` pointers are also set to `nil` when the class is dealloc'ed, that's the only practical difference with `assign`

Comment: @jere More correctly, weak pointers are set to `nil` when the objects they reference are deallocated. Edit: looks like you edited your comment.

Comment: It is true but also new API are using assign for delegate or dataSource instead of weak reference. Take a look to UICollectionView available from iOS 6.0. I cannot understand this. UICollectionView documentation says delegate and dataSource are handled as weak references but it's completely false. I can deallocate the dataSource of the UICollectionView and experience a crash as soon as the data are reloaded. Was hoping were weak handled behind the scenes keeping the assign in the .h for retro compatibility but it is not the case. I filed a bugReport just today. Waiting a response from Apple.

Comment: From Apple UICollectionView Documentation:
"The collection view maintains a weak reference to the delegate object."

"The collection view maintains a weak reference to the data source object."

Comment: Digged into the iOS API diff ... seems just a few amount of assign pointer properties were turned to weak references. The most used is certainly MKMapView that is available since 3.0 ... so, definitely I cannot understand why Apple does not turned all assign pointer properties to weak.

Comment: @Gabriele Any response from Apple?

Comment: @AlexanderVasenin my open issue was closed by Apple 1 weak later the opening marking it as Duplicated of 11103937 that is still open. Unfortunately I cannot access and watch the issue 11103937.

Comment: This was finally changed in iOS 9!

Answer (score 2):

UIKit is still built without ARC, therefore none of the UIKit classes can use weak references. Even newer classes like UICollectionView use assign for their delegate properties for this reason.

Answer (score -3):

Delegates should never be retained.  That's an easy path to a retain cycle.

Comment: The question was about weak vs. assign.

Comment: Not useful, but true)